Blender Indirect Only Render Cuts Off Glossy/Reflection
I want to render an animation in separate layers, with Smoke (Volumetric) on one layer and the Scene (Mesh) on another. But I ran into a problem—when I enable Indirect Only for the smoke Collection (Domain), the Glossy/Reflection of the smoke gets cut off in the Render, even though it looks fine in the Viewport.

*The image below shows a simple scene without any extra Objects, Render Layers, or Compositing.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Different Sample settings
Disabling Denoise
Disabling Motion Blur
Disabling Depth of Field in the Camera
Increasing all Max Bounces to 12 under Render > Light Paths
Render > Light Paths > Clamping > Indirect Light - testing different
values
Enabling/disabling Render > Film > Transparent
Toggling Object Visibility for both the Mesh and the Domain
Testing different Domain (Gas) sizes, with and without intersecting
the Mesh
Setting up the smoke Shader with both Principled Volume and Emission
Adjusting Clip Start/End for the Camera
Moving everything to a new Scene



You could try going into the object property panel (the orange square with the 4 corner pieces), go to "Visibility" -> "Ray Visibility" -> and uncheck "Camera". This should render everything of the smoke but not the direct "image" of the smoke

@Marius i just tested this method, and you know what? it’s the same - the reflection is still cut off :(

Hhhmm, Okay. Open the Shader Editor for your Smoke object. Get a light path node, a Transparency node and a mix shader node. Take the "is camera Ray" output from the light path node and plug it into the mix shaders Factor, than plug in the transparency and smoke material (I'm not sure on top of my head which one should be above and bellow, just try it out). Check and make sure that your transparent bounces are high enough and not limited by the overall bounce limit. Report back if this works, I'm rooting for you :D

@Marius could you please check it to make sure i didn’t do anything wrong? https://imgur.com/a/Pa55OFC

Haha, Well it does not look wrong. btw. I admire your commitment but when something does not work with 20 bounces it will also not work with 128 bounces :D

I will have a look at your file and report back

I have looked at your file and found a solution. In the Rendered Image You can see how it looks if you connect the "is camera Ray" directly to the factor of the mix node. this way you still get the shadow of the smoke on the floor. If you don't want the shadow, you can use a Math Node set to "Add" and connect it as you can see in the shader nodes. This will give you the current Viewport image you can see in the Screenshot (on the right). I hope this helps :D 

this is it! you’re a lifesaver!!! i’ll have to mess with render layers to apply two different materials to the same object, but that’s a minor detail. THANKS A LOT!!!

Happy I could help!
